# wxWidgets, wxCheckBox label sensitive

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm trying to get wxCheckBox to have sensitive label like it is in some other toolkit's.
It is often too delicate to aim on little box so whole area with label would be much convenient way to change a state.

But I can't find a way to do it.
Any help would be appreciate.

wxWidgets 2.8, Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: What version are you using?  What platform are you running on?  For me, v2.9.3 on Windows, wxCheckBox responds to clicks anywhere on the box or label.

Comment: Sorry. I am using Ubuntu and v2.8 and state changes only when I click to check box, not to label. Maybe is some "style" involved here? Because Gtk checkbox on Linux also responds on whole area.

Comment: Try with wxALIGN_RIGHT style, did your checkbox behaves a same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm this is a bug in wxWidgets GTK for `wxALIGN_RIGHT` check-boxes. If we take a quick look at the [source code](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/browser/wxWidgets/trunk/src/gtk/checkbox.cpp) for the wxCheckBox we can see that right aligned controls are created as two seperate parts, a label and a check box and that the label is never connected to to respond to click events. If you create a ticket on the [wxWidgets bug tracker](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/) then I am sure someone will fix it.